# Control the plot instruction through the 'display' argument

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to use the `display` argument for the `plot` instruction, but I do not know what type of variable to use for that. I tried in several ways, but nothing worked.

For example, I would like to plot the `close` value at the last bar of the chart. Is it possible to use the `display` argument for that, rather than sending `na` values or changing the plot color for the rest of the bars?

Thank you!

Alex

```
//@version=5
indicator("")

var string d = na

if (barstate.islast)
    d := "display.all"
else
    d := "display.none"

plot(close, color=#000000, linewidth=3, style=plot.style_circles, display=d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, display cannot be a `series` value, i.e. it cannot change from one bar to another.

The `show_last` parameter of the `plot()` function might do what you want -- it will only show the plot on the last X bars. Note taht `show_last` also cannot be a `series` value.